# Getting Location details from Google Map in gwt

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt

I need to perform some tasks with google map,
1. first I need the user to be able to place only one marker
2. Then retrieve the city and other details such as street address

Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a minimal example to show how you could achieve what you're looking for:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel.get().add(new GoogleMaps());
}

private class GoogleMaps extends Composite {

    private MapWidget fMap;
    private Geocoder fCoder;
    private Marker fMarker;

    public GoogleMaps() {
        fMap = new MapWidget(LatLng.newInstance(47.0559084, 8.3114878), 6);
        fMap.setSize("300px", "300px");
        fCoder = new Geocoder();
        MarkerOptions options = MarkerOptions.newInstance();
        options.setDraggable(true);
        fMarker = new Marker(LatLng.newInstance(47.0559084, 8.3114878), options);
        fMap.addOverlay(fMarker);
        fMarker.setVisible(false);
        addHandlers();
        initWidget(fMap);
    }

    private void addHandlers() {
        fMap.addMapDoubleClickHandler(new MapDoubleClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onDoubleClick(MapDoubleClickEvent event) {
                if (event.getLatLng() != null) {
                    performReverseLookup(event.getLatLng());
                }
            }

        });

        fMarker.addMarkerDragEndHandler(new MarkerDragEndHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onDragEnd(MarkerDragEndEvent event) {
                LatLng point = event.getSender().getLatLng();
                if (point != null) {
                    performReverseLookup(point);
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private void performReverseLookup(final LatLng point) {
        fCoder.getLocations(point, new LocationCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JsArray<Placemark> locations) {
                if (locations.length() > 0) {
                    LatLng point = locations.get(0).getPoint();
                    fMarker.setLatLng(point);
                    fMarker.setVisible(true);
                    fMap.getInfoWindow().open(point, new InfoWindowContent(locations.get(0).getAddress()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode) {}
        });
    }
}
```

To your first point: Create only one instance of `Marker` and update its `LatLng` upon user interaction (done in `performReverseLookup()`).

Your second question: After performing the reverse lookup you can get the `Placemark` object out of the `locations` array and retrieve details like the address.

Comment: Thanks lots z00bs for taking your time and write all this. I will test it and let u know.

Comment: Hi, works great. Thanks very this will gonna save loosing lots of time. By the way, I am Noor from Mauritius, studying computer science and engineering.